# Possible to append existing object in DB? (Node + Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object I've saved to the database like so

```
var newObject = new PObject ({
                   value : 'before',
                       id :123456
               });

           newObject.save(function (err) {
       if (err) console.log ('Error on save!')
   });
```

If i just want to change value to 'after', is that possible without adding a new object and deleting the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use `update` with the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator:

```
PObject.update({id: 123456}, {$set: {value: 'after'}}, function(err) { ... });
```